# How to enable mysql remote access without grant all privileges

Tags: mysql

Need to access one mysql database for a user remotely. I know it will work if grant all privileges on all databases to that user, like:

```
grant all on \*.* to 'someone'@'%'
```

But I just want grant access permission to that user on the database specified, not every database, like:
`grant all on mydb.* to 'someone'@'%'`.
Unfortunately, remote access will be failed in this case.

Any idea to solve this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE ON yourdb.* To your_user@'192.162.1.1' identified by 'password';
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. @AJ93, Did you try it successfully before?